# how to setup this simple Elasticsearch Mapping in Elasticsearch-PHP?

Tags: php, elasticsearch, elasticsearch-5

Given in the end of the question is an terminal command showing a simple Elasticsearch mapping. I need to set up this kind of mapping for an index using Elasticsearch-PHP. And I need to do this at the time when I am indexing the data.

I know how to index in Elasticsearch-PHP. It will be something like

```
for($i = 0; $i < 100; $i++) {
    $params['body'][] = [
        'index' => [
            '_index' => 'my_index',
            '_type' => 'my_type',
        ]
    ];

    $params['body'][] = [
        'my_field' => 'my_value',
        'second_field' => 'some more values'
    ];
}

$responses = $client->bulk($params);
```

My question is that how will I set up a Mapping, *corresponding to the particular Mapping given below* in the elasticsearch-PHP format (I believe it will become an associative array, but I am not sure of further details)?

---

This is the example ES Mapping, that I want to convert to the format used in PHP:

```
PUT _template/packets
{
  "template": "packets-*",
  "mappings": {
    "pcap_file": {
      "dynamic": "false",
      "properties": {
        "timestamp": {
          "type": "date"
        },
        "layers": {
          "properties": {
            "ip": {
              "properties": {
                "ip_ip_src": {
                  "type": "ip"
                },
                "ip_ip_dst": {
                  "type": "ip"
                }
              }
            }
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't update your mapping - you don't have to `put` mapping each time you re-index data into elasticsearch. But if you do, of you create index with new name you can do this:

```
$put = [
    'mappings' => [
        // your mapping here
    ],
];
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'http://yourHost:9200/yourIndex');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST, 'PUT');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, json_encode($put));
curl_exec($ch);
```

or you can use elasticsearch package:

```
$params = [
    'index' => 'yourIndex',
    'body' => [
        'mappings' => [
            // your mapping here
        ]
    ]
];
$response = $client->indices()->create($params);
```

Comment: Hey thank you; can you also tell me how I will write a mapping (in PHP) corresponding the mapping shown here: https://pastebin.com/H7QEWhNN

Comment: That is, how will I populate the array you have assigned to `'mappings'` in your code above?